# Windows 8.1 loses connection to network share

Tags: windows-8.1, domain-name-system

In my domain we have a network share but one of my users loses connection to it. She has a Windows 8.1 Enterprise machine, added to domain, always logged on domain user. The network share has permission set on domain users. She's connected via wifi.

Everyday she comes to work and after a little bit of time, she loses connection to mapped shares. After computer restart she gains back the connection.

I've investigated the issue and after she loses connection to shares I've tried to trace network traffic to the share. I've found that she has something wrong with DNS because at the time she doesn't have connection to shares, the share IP is changed from our address to some odd address.

I've encountered this:
nslookup shareName - gives an odd IP;
nslookup shareName.domain - gives the right IP;

Checked hosts file - no additional records;
Tried ipconfig /flushdns - no success;
When the connection to shares is lost she still has internet and every other service via network.

Comment: Have you tried doing a reverse lookup on the unknown IP address?

Comment: What DNS servers are configured on her computer?

Comment: @Scott: yes I've did a reverse lookup and didn't find any host with this adress

Comment: @joeqwerty: Her computer is configured with our DNS' which have correctly configured aliases for the network share.